# Cannot change keystore password

Tags: android, keytool

When I use the keytool -list -v -keystore command and it asks for the keystore password, I just press enter (blank password) and it lists the Keys from the keystore.

Although, if I try to use the keytool -passwd -keystore command, it doesn't accept a blank password as the above command.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you upload project into market? Didn't upload means create new keystore

Comment: Yes, I already have a Project uploaded with this keystore.

Comment: Without `keystore` password we can't do anything. Better uninstall create new project with different package and then create new keystore. there is no way

Comment: So is the keystore password really blank or not? If it is, you could try using a tool such as protecle to export the key+certificate to a new keystore and set a password: http://portecle.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I thought it could have blank password because keytool -list command accepts for the same keystore a password or a blank password. I've tested this using debug.keystore.

Answer (score 0):

All JKS key stores are password-protected. However, as you have found, you can list the contents of a key store without knowing the password:

```
$ keytool -list
Enter keystore password:

*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
* you must provide your keystore password.                  *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 4 entries
```

Note the warning you get if you enter a blank password. If you want to change the password you will need to know the current one, otherwise you will have to recreate a new keystore and re-import all the public certificates. Any private keys you should consider as lost once the password is lost.